# Chipsee 7 inch LCD support in Linux kernel 3.14

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, beaglebone

Has anybody ported Chipsee 7 inch LCD on Linux kernel 3.14 or later ?

Is there any patch available for the same ?

If no patches any suggestion porting Chipsee LCD support from Linux kernel 3.8 to Linux kernel 3.14 ?